# Hostinger аналог

Tags: хостинг

Подскажите аналог виртуального хостинга [Hostinger](http://api.hostinger.com.ua/redir/1745068). Интересует хостинг с подобной к [Hostinger](http://api.hostinger.com.ua/redir/1745068) ценовой политикой и наличием бесплатного хостинга или тестового периода (для проверки функциональности и надежности перед покупкой). Наличие поддержки PHP, MySQL и PostgreSQL обязательно.Заранее спасибо!

---

Сразу отвечу на вопрос: "Чем не устраивает Hostinger?" Всем устраивает, только вот там нету поддержки PostgreSQL. И потому, прежде чем переходить на [Hostinger](http://api.hostinger.com.ua/redir/1745068) с бесплатного аккаунта на платный, хотелось бы узнать: мб существуют другие подобные варианты, но умеющие работать с PostgreSQL.

Comment: защитил вопрос от спамеров (ниже отметился один) пока общественность раздумывает, стоит ли закрывать этот вопрос.

Comment: Топикстратер ответ на свой вопрос получил ещё в 2013 году, подобные вопросы вообще всегда слишком субьективны (никто толком не описывает критерии) и быстро устаревают. Пусть будет закрытым, чтобы спамеры, которые хотят порекламироваться в трастовых страницах не лезли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может VPS лучше арендовать? я, например, чейчас беру за 131руб/мес -- Virtual CPU 800Mhz, 400Mb memory, 6000Mb disk
что хочешь то и ставишь.

Comment: а обслуживать самому? что, если некому апач обновить?

Comment: каких то особых проблем в этом не вижу. во вторых на большинстве таких хостингов системы уже предустановлены, управление все делается через вебинтерфейс. Да и обновление апачей и т.п. не каждый день происходит. На крайний случай можно заказать разовую техподдержку со стороны хостера.

Answer (score 0):

А вы искали ? [let me google for you](http://hosting101.ru/catalog/postgresql)